# Error message when launching command line and unable to update or install

Tags: command-line, 15.04

I get an error message on Ubuntu 15.04. I'm unable to install anything and when I open my command line this error pops up:

```
bash: /home/lea/.bashrc: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/lea/.bashrc: line 1: `export PATH=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
```

Comment: Run `gedit ~/.bashrc`, and edit line 1, then save and exit.

Comment: @mikewhatever  Thanks. Please what exactly i'm I to edit on line one

Comment: Can you please include a link to your `/home/lea/.bashrc` in your question?

Comment: @ThomasW.: I doubt that this issue is specific to 15.04. If OP somehow manages to upgrade then the broken `.bashrc` will likely persist.

Comment: Hello  @Ndi Britha A.Lea, I think you should have this as first line `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells. `

Comment: I edited the first line from `export  PATH=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.` to  `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.` See my answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the command line I typed:

   ```
   gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. The `gedit ~/.bashrc` will open.

   It Looks like this bellow:

   ```
   PATH=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
   #see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
   # for examples
   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   case $- in
       *i*) ;;
         *) return;;
   esac

   # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
   # See bash(1) for more options
   HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

   # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
   shopt -s histappend

   # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
   HISTSIZE=1000
   HISTFILESIZE=2000

   # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
   # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
   shopt -s checkwinsize

   # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
   # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.

   #shopt -s globstar
   # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
   [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

   # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
   if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
       debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
   fi

   # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
   case "$TERM" in
       `xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
   esac

   # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
   # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
   # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
   #force_color_prompt=yes

   if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
       if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
       # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
       # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
       # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
           color_prompt=yes
       else
           color_prompt=
       fi
   fi

   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m
   \]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   fi
   unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
   # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
   case "$TERM" in
   xterm*|rxvt*)
       PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
   esac

   # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
   if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
       test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
       alias ls='ls --color=auto'
       #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
       #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
       alias grep='grep --color=auto'
       alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
       alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
   fi

   # colored GCC warnings and errors
   #export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
   # some more ls aliases
   alias ll='ls -alF'
   alias la='ls -A'
   alias l='ls -CF'

   # Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
   #   sleep 10; alert
   alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

   # Alias definitions.
   # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
   # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
   # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi

   # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
   # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
   # sources /etc/bash.bashrc).

   if ! shopt -oq posix; then
     if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
       . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
     elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
       . /etc/bash_completion
     fi
   fi
   ```
3. I edited the first line by deleting this:

   ```
   PATH=/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH
   ```
4. This is what you should have:

   ```
   # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
   #see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
   # for examples
   # If not running interactively, don't do anything
   case $- in
       *i*) ;;
         *) return;;
   esac

   # don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
   # See bash(1) for more options
   HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

   # append to the history file, don't overwrite it
   shopt -s histappend

   # for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
   HISTSIZE=1000
   HISTFILESIZE=2000

   # check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
   # update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
   shopt -s checkwinsize

   # If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
   # match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
   #shopt -s globstar
   # make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
   [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

   # set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
   if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
       debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
   fi

   # set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)

   case "$TERM" in
       xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
   esac

   # uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
   # off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
   # should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
   #force_color_prompt=yes

   if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
       if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
      # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
      # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
      # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
           color_prompt=yes
       else
           color_prompt=
       fi
   fi

   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m
   \]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   else
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
   fi

   unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

   # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
   case "$TERM" in
   xterm*|rxvt*)
       PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
       ;;
   *)
       ;;
   esac

   # enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
   if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
       test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
       alias ls='ls --color=auto'
       #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
       #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
       alias grep='grep --color=auto'
       alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
       alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
   fi

   # colored GCC warnings and errors
   #export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
   # some more ls aliases
   alias ll='ls -alF'
   alias la='ls -A'
   alias l='ls -CF'
   # Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
   #   sleep 10; alert
   alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

   # Alias definitions.
   # You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
   # ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
   # See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
       . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi

   # enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
   # this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
   # sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
   if ! shopt -oq posix; then
     if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
       . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
     elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
       . /etc/bash_completion
     fi
   fi
   ```
5. Then I saved the file and exited.
6. And then I relaunched my terminal.